# Hide product categories and taxonomy terms in menu if empty

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, menus, taxonomy, sub-menu

I've been researching this and had no luck so far.

I have a WooCommerce store with a main menu showing product categories (product_cat) and brands (yith_product_brand) which is a custom taxonomy.

I want to hide categories and brands if they are empty. Do you know a way to achieve this, either by using a plugin or adding a function/filter to the functions.php file? If so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the custom taxonomy, however I have used this code before to remove empty categories. You can add it to functions.php.

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'nav_remove_empty_category_menu_item', 10, 3 );
function nav_remove_empty_category_menu_item ( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $nopost = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE count = 0" );
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        if ( ( 'taxonomy' == $item->type ) && ( in_array( $item->object_id, $nopost ) ) ) {
            unset( $items[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```